# How can I use const enum in HTML angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, enums, angular-template

I am using the latest version of `Angular` and try to access the const enum at HTML, quite not sure how can I do that. Here is the enum

```
export const enum InputTypes {
    DragDrop = "dragDrop",
    Text = "text",
    Search = "search"
}
```

I need to declare `const` in front of the `enum`, due to the enum export issue. Things I tried

```
*ngIf="inputTypes.Search"
```

**First approach**

```
export class ChipsComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() { }
    ngOnInit(): void {}
    public get inputTypes(): typeof InputTypes {
      return InputTypes; 
    }
  }
```

**Second approach**

```
export class ChipsComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() { }
    ngOnInit(): void {}
    inputTypes = InputTypes;
  }
```

**Error**

```
'const' enums can only be used in property or index access expressions or the right hand side of an import declaration or export assignment or type query
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "preserveConstEnums": true
    }
```

If I haven't declare the enum as const the above approach will work, but quite not sure with the  const value

There is an open issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25963 One solution was

```
templateImports: [someConstant, UserStatus, isDevMode]
```

This would not work, but the below could:

```
templateImports: {someConstant, UserStatus, isDevMode}
```

Even this one is not working, getting error on `templateImports`

Comment: Have you enabled [`preserveConstEnums`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#preserveConstEnums) in your `tsconfig.json` file? At this time of writing it defaults to `false`.

Comment: @miqh Well I did same issue.

Comment: I think we can't use the `enum` directly on the template, assign its value to a variable in the component and then access that variable on the template.

Comment: @NicholasK can you please provide one example. It should be const enum

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript supports [Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), which are constant strings, combine that feature with Unions and you have a structure much similar to an enum, but with much less problems.

**Example**:

```ts
type InputTypes = 'dragDrop' | 'text' | 'search';

export class ChipsComponent {
    @Input() appType: AppType;
}
```

```html
<div *ngIf="appType === 'text'">
  ...
</div>
```

Literal Types are just pre defined strings, so there's no problem using it on Angular Templates, it even code-complete on your desired editor/IDE. It's interesting mention too that the TypeScript compiler will block any compilation that uses a string value different than the ones you define.

Comment: Don't want to hard code 'text'. that's why I need enum